# ИЕ6 и 7 игнорируют свойство z-index у элементов.

Tags: xhtml, html, вёрстка

Очень часто сталкиваюсь с проблемой, когда в ие 6-7 элементы с position:relative, накладываются на элементы с position:absolute, при этом на z-index браузеры не реагируют. Хотелось бы спросить отчего возникает такая ситуация и как с ней бороться. (Как пример выпадающий список с position:absolute и z-index:999 подлазит под тег h2 с position:relative, если отключить position:relative, то все работает ок)

Answer (score 1):

Это довольно известный баг в IE 6/7, описание проблемы и пример можно посмотреть [тут](http://therealcrisp.xs4all.nl/meuk/IE-zindexbug.html). Все дело в том, что элементы при позиционировании создают новый контекст стека.

В случае с Вашим примером, попробуйте у элемента `h2` установить `z-index: -1;`.
У меня просто была уже как-то подобная проблема, и это помогло.

Также есть [хорошая статья о свойстве z-index](http://dreamhelg.ru/2009/09/css-property-z-index/)

Цитата с [сайта о багах IE 6](http://www.virtuosimedia.com/dev/css/ultimate-ie6-cheatsheet-how-to-fix-25-internet-explorer-6-bugs#ie-z-index):

> If you're using the z-index property on positioned elements in Internet Explorer 6 or 7, the stacking index will reset to zero, causing a rendering error. The solution, pointed out by a person named baker, is to add a higher z-index to the parent element. In some cases, the parent element may also need to be assigned position:relative.

Comment: Статьи хорошие, однако в них нет рекомендаций как же с этим бороться, а если я добавляю z-index: -1, то заголовок просто пропадает.

Comment: странный результат.. я добавил еще цитату с решением с одного сайта о багах IE 6. Проблема решается посредством установки z-index на родительский элемент. Сам не пробовал, но это решение видел на ряде сайтов

Comment: Нашел ответ в нете, нужно родительскому блоку, который содержит выпадающий блок и относительно которого он позиционируется, ставить z-index, больший, чем у самого выпадающего блока и все ок.